# IOS 15 Ibeacon monitoring

Tags: ios, monitoring, ibeacon, region

I used ibeacon monitoring in background before version ios 15.

Used this code

```
  if let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "1345bbaa-0000-0000-0000-00000000bbbb") {
                let region = CLBeaconRegion(
                    proximityUUID: uuid,
                    identifier: "1345bbaa-0000-0000-0000-00000000bbbb")
                
                region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true
                region.notifyOnExit = true
                region.notifyOnEntry = true
                beaconRegions.append(region)
                
                locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: region)
            }
```

It doesn't work in this update.

In short, not called func

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion)

Do you know anything about these issues?

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have `always` location permission?

Comment: Sure. bluetooth permission allowd and location permission always allowd

Comment: In our extensive bug report about this issue (beacon monitoring specifically) the status has been updated to 'Potential fix identified - For a future OS update'.

Answer (score 1):

If this only fails in iOS 15, there's a bug there that will result in Apple not notifying you. [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70673842/1183411) shows how to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69303318/1461050)  showing that on my iPhone 11, beacon monitoring works fine before and after the iOS 15 update.  This includes source code and screenshots.  So this is clearly not a universal problem with iOS15.

It is unclear why you are having trouble with your phone.  You might try:

1. Reboot your phone and see if the problem goes away.
2. Install my test app mentioned in the link question above and follow my procedure to see if you can reproduce my results (you will need to change my ProximityUUiD in my code to match your beacon)

There are often bugs accompanied by a new OS release, so any clarification you can offer based on further tests maybe valuable.