# iBeacon Notifications Unreliable when AirPods Set to connect "Automatically"

Tags: ios, background, location, core-location, ibeacon

I'm building an app that relies on waking up and notifying the user when an iBeacon is detected and have discovered some really strange behaviour.

---

**On iOS15, when a user has AirPods paired to their device and the AirPods are set to connect `Automatically` the device will not reliably receive notifications that the iBeacon is in range.**

The reliability is very sporadic when set to `Automatically`. The user will have good days with reliable events or go ~10-120 minutes where their phone doesn't detect the beacon at all.

The setting is located under `Settings -> Bluetooth -> Airpods -> Connect to this Phone`

If set to `When last connected to this phone` the beacon events are received consistently.

---

For context:

- I've implemented the workaround to the prewarming bug described on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70673842/640196)
- I've only managed to reproduce on iOS15 so far
- I only use beacon region monitoring
- Range is not the issue. This occurs anywhere between standing next to the beacon and at the edge of signal limits.

**Has anybody else experience this issue and/or have a programmatic workaround?**

I'd rather not have to instruct users to change their AirPod settings!

Comment: We also have noticed the same thing and still goes on iOS 17 
We were struggling to understand why ibeacon regions stopped being monitored overnight and/or after a few hours of flawlessly working and we noticed that on a specific device that this was happening after we haven't used our Airpods (2nd gen) for a couple of days, every region enter and exit was monitored perfectly. After using the Airpods we lost the events. Anyone found a workaround with that? I see that this is the only post in the whole Internet about this issue!

Comment: I ended up filing a bug with Apple via Feedback Assistant and they asked for more info "Provide a sysdiagnose while using BT logging profile". Unfortunately, I haven't had time to grab the logs for them yet. That said, the `When last connected to this phone` selected detection has been reliable.