# iOS 15 does not wake up Xamarin Forms iOS app in background sometimes when app is killed

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, region-monitoring

I am experiencing an issue with Xamarin Forms (iOS) app which does BLE beacon scanning in the background (App killed state).

The goal is to wake up app when user enters in a beacon region. This app works quite smoothly on iOS 12,13 & 14. The day when I updated my iPhone to iOS 15, background detection/DidRangeBeacons function stopped executing for some reason in killed state. Let's say If I launched app today, entered region and left, everything works fine and it will work fine for 3-4 number of tests. If I come to this region next day, app will not be awoken on 2nd day or 3rd day. I have to restart my phone to get it working again, but this is not something that users will want to do.

Does anyone know If there are any breaking changes in iOS15 with regards to beacons detection in iOS 15.

Your help is appreciated !

Comment: It is a known issue in iOS 15 and it should be fixed in iOS15.1 , refer to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690452 , and for workaround you can follow the steps in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69303318/8187800.